# Funcion para Ordenar los Indices de un Arreglo

Tags: c, array-bidimensional

Buenas tengo un trabajo para la universidad que me pide lo siguiente:

"Reubica los índices del arreglo d según un orden ascendente de los elementos del arreglo a."

llevo como unos 5 días tratando de hacerlo y aun no consigo el como puedo hacer que me imprima solo los índices en forma ascendente, hasta ahora lo único que he logrado es usar el método burbuja para ordenar los valores de forma ascendente sin embargo como ya mencione antes no se como puedo hacer para llevar un control sobre los índices acá abajo dejo el pedazo de código de la función en donde se realiza el proceso, un saludo.

````
{
 int i,l,aux;
 Arreglo auxiliar; //arreglo auxiliar declarado para llevar un control sobre los índices pero sin éxito
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     for(l=0;l<n;l++)
     {
         if(d[l]>d[l+1])
         {
             aux=d[l];
             d[l]=d[l+1];
             d[l+1]=aux;
         }
     }
 }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     printf("|%d",d[i]);
 }
 printf("|");
}```
````

Comment: ¿Que contiene el arreglo inicial?

Comment: esto parece c.. es c?

Comment: un par de for anidados no es un metodo de ordenamiento burbuja...

Comment: buenas respondiendo a sus preguntas, el arreglo incial el ususario lo digita por teclado este debe ser de un tamaño de N numeros, de igual forma los valores del arreglo inicial los digita el usuario por teclado(con arreglo inicial me refiero al arrelgo a), el arreglo son los mismo valores que tiene a esto pues basicamente porque en el trabajo se me exige que en ningun momento los valores del arreglo a cambien de ubicacion

Comment: Y, en cuanto a las preguntas de gbianchi, si es lenguaje c y en cuanto a la otra, soy nuevo viendo arreglos y apenas estoy comenzando la carrera por lo que estoy abierto a que se me corrija si me equivoco, pero hasta donde yo tengo entendido asi se hace el bubble sort en una funcion

Answer (score 2):

Puedes declarar un arreglo para los índices:

```
int índices [n]; 
int auxIndice;
```

Luego inicializarías este arreglo a través de un **ciclo for** donde cada valor del arreglo sería su propia posición o índice:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    indice[i] = i;
}
```

Posteriormente en la parte donde ordenas los valores del arreglo original tendrías tus dos **ciclos for** y dentro de la condición donde haces la comparación de las posiciones del arreglo original tendrías esto:

```
if(d[l] > d[l + 1])
{
    aux = d[l];
    d[l] = d[l + 1];
    d[l+1] = aux;
    auxIndice = indice[l];
    indice[l] = índice[l + 1];
    índice[l + 1] = auxIndice;
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es ordenar el arreglo original y en paralelo ordenar el arreglo de índices, los dos terminarían ordenados el original por sus valores y el arreglo de índices también por sus valores que en este caso su valor guarda los índices que representan los índices del arreglo original.

Posteriormente imprimiría el arreglo de índices.