# Como imprimir los indices originales de un array ordenado?

Tags: java, array, indices

Tengo que escribir un programa que pregunte al usuario el tamaño de arreglo, luego introduzca los valores para el arreglo, imprima el arreglo, ordénarlo, imprima nuevamente el arreglo ordenado y un arreglo con los índices originales de los elementos del arreglo. Por ejemplo:

A = {8, 10, 6, 14, 2}  --> arreglo original

A = {2, 6, 8, 10, 14} --> arreglo ordenado

I = {4, 2, 0 , 1,  3} --> índices originales de los elementos

Ya tengo hecho todo, lo unico que me falta es imprimir los indices originales de los elementos, intente con un ciclo for, como se puede ver en el codigo, pero obviamente no funciono...

```
public class Arreglos {
public static void main(String[]args){
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("De que tamaño desea que sea su arreglo?");
    int ta = sc.nextInt();
    int [] a = new int[ta];
    System.out.println("El tamaño del arreglo es de "+a.length+" espacios");
    System.out.println("\nIntroduzca los valores deseados: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    
    //imprime arreglo
    System.out.println("\nSu Arreglo: "+Arrays.toString(a));
    //ordena arreglo
    Arreglos ar = new Arreglos();
    ar.quicksort(a);
    //imprime arreglo ordenado
    System.out.println("\nSu Arreglo ordenado de manera ascendente: "+Arrays.toString(a));


    //imprime arreglo con los indices originales <-------------       
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(a[i]);
      }
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398093/funcion-para-ordenar-los-indices-de-un-arreglo/398217#398217  revisa este enlace, puede darte ideas

Answer (score 1):

Si ordenaste el arreglo original no vas a poder imprimir los indices originales.

Lo más simple (no muy eficiente) es:

1. hacer una copia del array original, sus elementos no su referencia  (arrOriginal = arrCopia es un error).
2. Ordenar la copia.
3. Con dos bucles anidados (for-for o for-while) buscar el primer elemento del **arrayOrdenado** en el **arrayDesordenado** al encontrarlo, imprimir el indice de este ultimo y salir del bucle interno.
4. Repetir el punto 3 para todos los elementos del arrayOrdenado.

Con dos bucles for:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrOrdenado.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < arrOriginal.length; k++) {
            if( arrOrdenado[i] == arrOriginal[k]) {
                System.out.print(k+" "); // imprime el indice del elemento en el array original
                k = arrOriginal.length;         //  fuerza la salida del bucle interno
            }
        }
    }
```

o una versión más estilizada

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrOrdenado.length; i++) {
        while( arrOrdenado[i] != arrOriginal[j] ) j++;
        System.out.print(j+" ");
        j=0;
    }
```